# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
          field :'lastapple info', type: String
                 ^
```

with this method right here:

```
  def eval_mongo(klass, field)
    _field = field['field'].to_sym
    _type = FieldType.where(_id: field['field_type_id']).first.type_from_field
    klass.class_eval <<-EOS
          field :'#{ _field }', type: #{ _type }
    EOS
  end
```

I stare at this and I cannot figure out where the error is. Since I am using heredocs, I do not require a do end for class_eval. In fact, it works fine in the console and I used it before so I know this cannot be the issue. So then what is the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `field :#{ _field}, type: #{ _type }`? You want to build a symbol, not a string, right?

Comment: @marc I need the string because last_apple info without a string will produce an invalid method with a space and cause an undefined info error.

Comment: That should work. What Ruby version are you using? Using `eval` is always highly worrying, so I'd hope you can avoid this by using `klass.send(_field.to_sym, _type)`

Comment: @tadman ruby '2.1.2' and I know it should work, I used it elsewhere and it works fine. Just in this specific method it does not work.

Comment: It is very hard to see any error here. I'd recommend eliminating syntax sugar (use `self.`, method parens, curly braces around hash args), seeing if it works, then adding back sugary bits one by one until it breaks again.

Comment: Are you getting the syntax error when the Ruby file is being loaded or when the `class_eval` is run? Are you sure the error is in that method and not really caused by a typo above it?

Comment: @muistooshort when the class_eval is run. It happens in Rails application. When I delete that method and copy the same exact contents into calling method, the error does not occur, which boggles my mind.

Comment: What happens if you try to call `field` with a string as the first argument rather than a symbol? I added the mongoid tag to help clarify what this `field` method is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use the `field` name for too many things in here:

```
def eval_mongo(klass, field)
  _field = field['field'].to_sym
  _type = FieldType.where(_id: field['field_type_id']).first.type_from_field
  klass.class_eval <<-EOS
    field :'#{ _field }', type: #{ _type }
  EOS
end
```

`field` is an argument to `eval_mongo` but you also want to use it as a class method name inside the `class_eval` call. Inside the `class_eval`, Ruby thinks you want the `field` argument so you get a syntax error. If you name the argument `f` instead:

```
def eval_mongo(klass, f)
  _field = f['field'].to_sym
  _type = FieldType.where(_id: f['field_type_id']).first.type_from_field
  klass.class_eval <<-EOS
    field :'#{ _field }', type: #{ _type }
  EOS
end
```

then things should work.

---

I wish I could offer a clear explanation of what's going on here but I can't. Instead, I'll summarize what I found by wandering around the MRI source and trying to tease out the behavior through experimentation. This approach is very error prone but it is often all we have with Ruby.

The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) says:

> **class_eval(string [, filename [, lineno]]) → obj**
>
> Evaluates the string or block in the context of *mod*, except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected. [...]

This is, as usual with Ruby, not quite detailed or specific enough to be terribly useful.

If we look at the source, we'll see that `class_eval` is actually [`rb_mod_module_eval` in `vm_eval.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_5/vm_eval.c#L1677) which just calls [`specific_eval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_5/vm_eval.c#L1560) which calls [`eval_under`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_5/vm_eval.c#L1546) which calls [`eval_string_with_cref`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_5/vm_eval.c#L1180) with a `Qnil` value for the `scope` argument. That `scope` is handled by this:

```
if (!NIL_P(scope)) {
    /* ... */
}
else {
    rb_control_frame_t *cfp = rb_vm_get_ruby_level_next_cfp(th, th->cfp);

    if (cfp != 0) {
        block = *RUBY_VM_GET_BLOCK_PTR_IN_CFP(cfp);
        base_block = &block;
        base_block->self = self;
        base_block->iseq = cfp->iseq;   /* TODO */
    }
    else {
        rb_raise(rb_eRuntimeError, "Can't eval on top of Fiber or Thread");
    }
}
```

and then the `base_block` is used to compile the source code string. I'm not terribly familiar with the MRI source but that looks like it is intentionally setting things up to use the scope around the `class_eval`.

A simplified example might help:

```
class K
  def self.field(*args)
    puts args.inspect
  end
end

def eval_mongo(klass, f)
  klass.class_eval <<-EOS
    field :'#{f}', type: String
    f
  EOS
end

puts eval_mongo(K, 'pancakes house').inspect
```

That will say:

```
[:"pancakes house", {:type=>String}]
"pancakes house"
```

If you leave the name alone but call `field` with a string argument:

```
def eval_mongo(klass, field)
  klass.class_eval <<-EOS
    field '#{field}', type: String
    field
  EOS
end
```

then it also works and says:

```
["pancakes house", {:type=>String}]
"pancakes house"
```

but if we use `field` as the argument name and use a symbol:

```
def eval_mongo(klass, field)
  klass.class_eval <<-EOS
    field :'#{field}', type: String
    field
  EOS
end
```

we get our syntax error:

```
in `class_eval': (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    field :'pancakes house', type: String
           ^
```

Interestingly enough, you'll get the same syntax error if you try use the somewhat obscure string pasting feature of Ruby:

```
> s = 'a' 'b'
 => "ab"
```

with a symbol:

```
> s = 'a' :'b'
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
s = 'a' :'b'
         ^
```

Perhaps different things are being evaluated to different times and Ruby is getting confused about what's a string and what isn't.

This behavior is surprising and unexpected to me so I'm tempted to call this a bug or perhaps a misfeature, I could be missing something obvious though. It would be nice if `class_eval`'s behavior was better specified (with justification and rationale for surprising behavior) but that seems to go against the fast'n'loose Ruby culture.

I would appreciate it if anyone could clarify why this happens.